# 'npm start' fails after not finding the module '..\scripts\start.js'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to run `npm start`, but it keeps failing.
I've removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and ran `npm install`. It still failed.

I've tried removing `node_modules` again, and this time I ran `npm install -g npm@latest`, and reinstalled them, but still, it just keeps faling.

This is the terminal log I'm getting:

```
> foy@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy
> node scripts/start.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy\scripts\start.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! foy@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foy@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-16T12_08_00_997Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy>
```

And this is the complete report

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Yanay\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle foy@0.1.0~prestart: foy@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: foy@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Android;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Notepad++;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\flutter\bin;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.2\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin;C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
9 verbose lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy
10 silly lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node scripts/start.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle foy@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: foy@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yanay\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid foy@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Yanay\Documents\Coding\foy
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Yanay\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.9
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error foy@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the foy@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Check if you run `npm run` in the same path where `node-modules` are installed

Comment: @VladPopa yes I am. I am running it from VS code so basically just opening the built it terminal and tunning it, while I'm on my project. o be clear though, I am certain that I am running it from the same directory as where the `node_modules` are

Comment: I did this when I had this problem `npm cache clean --force`   and `npm install`  and  `npm i react-scripts`

Comment: @zahrazamani Still doesn't work unfortunately. Losing my mind here